# OpenGL|ES add shadow / shadow mapping

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, shadow, shadow-mapping

What is the easiest way to add shadows to a 3d Object?

I have objects information(vertices, texCoordinates, normals, indices) stored in arrays.

There are some frameworks like [isgl3d](https://code.google.com/p/isgl3d/) for iOS that allow users to load 3d .obj files and add shadows, but they adds a lot of unuseful stuff and aren't multiplatform(iOS + android)

What would be the easiest way to add shadow to a 3d object? 
Could you show/link to a working example(iOS/Android)?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, you find a library or some implementation that you can compile to your platform. Shadowing in 3d is not obvious and as I know, OpenGL does not implement it.

Techniques I'm aware of are Shadow volumes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume
and probably the easier one is (for which I could not find a link) is when you map your object's vertices to a plane, for example to the ground and draw the object again in black.

Comment: the second one is called 'projected geometry' and is described here: http://www.slideshare.net/stefan_b/advanced-lighting-for-interactive-applications